# Proving a recursive sequence of polynomials is equal to a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

The sequence of polynomials $f_k(x)$ is defined recursively as:

$$f_1(x)=x$$ and $$f_k(x)=x(1-x)f'_{k-1}(x) +kxf_{k-1}(x). $$

I also know that $f_k(1)=k!$ and $f'_k(0)=1$.

The identity I want to prove is:

$$\frac{f_k(x)}{(1-x)^{k+1}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^kx^n $$

assuming that $|x|<1.$

---

So far I've done this:

Starting with the LHS:

$$\frac{f_k(x)}{(1-x)^{k+1}}=\frac{x(1-x)f'_{k-1}(x) +kxf_{k-1}(x)}{(1-x)^{k+1}}=\frac{xf'_{k-1}(x)}{(1-x)^{k}}+\frac{kxf_{k-1}(x)}{(1-x)^{k+1}}$$

And I know the RHS expands to:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^kx^n=1^kx^1+2^kx^2+3^kx^3+...$$

After this I'm not sure how to link the two sides.

Can anyone give me any hints on how to manipulate the LHS further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps assuming this inductively will help, since then you know by the inductive hypothesis,
$$
\frac{f_{k-1}(x)}{(1-x)^k} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{k-1}x^n,
$$
or in other words,
$$
f_{k-1}(x) = (1-x)^k \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{k-1}x^n,
$$
and you can find $f_{k-1}'(x)$ explicitly. Use it and prove for $f_k(x)$, and validate for $k=0$ or $k=1$ and you are done for all integer $k$ after your initial validation...

Comment: So validating for $k=1$ we know that $f_1(x)=x$ so $$f_1(x)=x=(1-x)^2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^1 x^n$$ and since $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$$ then $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^1 x^n=\frac{x}{(x-1)^2}$$ Therefore $$RHS=\frac{x(1-x)^2}{(x-1)^2}=x.$$ Therefore LHS and RHS are equal, thus the identity is true for $k=1.$

Comment: Using the induction hypothesis we assume that the identity holds for k-1 so $$f_{k-1}(x)=(1-x)^k \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{k-1}x^n.$$ Then we need to show that it is true for k, therefore $$f_k(x)=(1-x)^{k+1} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^kx^n$$ where $$f_{k}(x)=x(1-x)f'_{k-1}(x)+kxf_{k-1}(x).$$ Then by subbing in for $f_{k-1}(x)$ you get: $$x(1-x)f'_{k-1}(x)+kx(1-x)^k\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{k-1}x^n.$$ Is this correct up to here? I'm unsure how to find $f'_{k-1}(x)$ explicitly as you said. I know that  $$f_{k-1}(x)=(1-x)^k\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{k-1}x^n$$  but I'm not sure how to differentiate the series?

Comment: @DavinaGoodman base case above is correct. Inductive step, too. Note that $$\frac{d}{dx} \left[\sum n^{k-1}x^n\right] = \sum \frac{d}{dx} \left[n^{k-1}x^n\right] = \sum n^k x^{n-1} $$

Answer (score 1):

You already have
$$\frac{f_k(x)}{(1-x)^{k+1}}=\frac{x\,f'_{k-1}(x)}{(1-x)^{k}}+\frac{k\,x\,f_{k-1}(x)}{(1-x)^{k+1}}=x\,\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\,\frac{f_{k-1}(x)}{(1-x)^k}\,.$$
Then, use induction on $k$.